# Merging two dataframes in a loop change original dataframe in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have a list of dataframes

```
dataframes = [a, b, c, d]
```

and one dataframe `additionalInformation`  containing information I need for the merge.

Is there a way to `join` the dataframes in a loop and overwrite the original dataframe?

```
for index, df in enumerate(dataframes):
    dataframes[index] = pd.merge(df, additionalInformation, how="left", left_on="cat", right_on="cat")
```

However, this is not updating the dataframes.
When I do a

```
a.columns
```

The columns from `additionalInformation` are not merged... When I perform a

```
a = pd.merge(a, additionalInformation, how="left", left_on="cat", right_on="cat")
```

It works.
How would I merge dataframes in a loop and overwrite the original dataframe?

Comment: Never change the content of a loop on its elements. This is a general rule in Python (and in general). The solution: work on a copy, or create a new output and merge it later.

Comment: When you assign something to `a` you make `a` point towards this object, whether or not `a` pointed to something else is irrelevant an other objects won't be modified. If you do `a = 1 ; a = 2`, do you expect `1` to be equal to `2`?

Comment: check the `dataframes[0]`.  `pd.merge` returns a new object and won't mutate the original `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the DataFrame, you have to assign to the dataframe's content, not the variable.

**If the cat values in additionalInformation are unique** (thus making the left-merge keep the same number of row), you can use:

```
for index, df in enumerate(dataframes):
    merged = pd.merge(df, additionalInformation, how="left", on="cat")
    dataframes[index].loc[:, merged.columns] = merged
```

If the values are not unique, this will truncate the output